# hello place tallk me where is the erorr in this code

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

```js
$(document).ready(function(){  
    $('#nav-b  .navbar-item li a').click(function(){    
        $('#nav-b .navbar-item li a').removeClass('active');            
        $(this).addClass('active');  
    }); 
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light  dark bg-dark ">
 <div class="container">
  <div class="navbar-brand"> <h5>Mohammed <span>Hassan</span></h5></div>
  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
   <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>


  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
   <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto" id="nav-b">
    <li class="nav-item active mr-auto">
     <a class="nav-link" href="#"   >Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
     <a class="nav-link" href="#" data-scroll="Skills">Skills</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
     <a class="nav-link" href="#"  data-scroll="Portfolio">Portfolio</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
     <a class="nav-link" href="#"  data-scroll="Contact">Contact</a>
    </li>
   </ul>

  </div>
 </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: sorry code query:                                                                                                                                            $(document).ready(function(){
 $('#nav-b  .navbar-item li a').click(function(){
   $('#nav-b .navbar-item li a').removeClass('active');
   $(this).addClass('active');
 });
});

Comment: *- where is the error in this code? - no such word "toggler"* I mean try to make your question more precise. Tell what is your problem and show what have you done to solve it.

Comment: `navbar-item` is not the right class. Did you mean `navbar-nav`?

Answer (score 0):

In

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
  $('#nav-b .navbar-item li a').click(function(){ 
    $('#nav-b .navbar-item li a').removeClass('active');
    $(this).addClass('active'); 
  }); 
});
```

You do not have navbar-item in your html so try:

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
  $('#nav-b .nav-item li a').click(function(){ 
    $('#nav-b .nav-item li a').removeClass('active');
    $(this).addClass('active'); 
  }); 
});
```